# Regex for SOQL Query String

Tags: java, regex, salesforce

I have the below SOQL query:

`SELECT Description,(Select Name,Id from Contacts) , Account.Name, (Select Id from Contacts) from Account`

I want to apply regex in java to extract following -

`SELECT Description, Account.Name from Account`

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want to extract a constant string from the SQL query itself? Or is this just an example of a regex you want to apply across many queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution custom tailored to the expression given:

```
String query = "SELECT Description,(Select Name,Id from Contacts) , Account.Name, (Select Id from Contacts) from Account";

// Remove all subqueries (things in parenthesis)
// Remove doubled commas (even with space in between)
// Remove a comma before the from
String answer = query
    .replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")
    .replaceAll(",\\s*,", ",")
    .replaceAll(",\\s*from", " from");
```